# I am trying to put in const data = to the ${body.email}. To be simple, it's for sending e-mail while just typing in the front

Tags: email, next.js, sendgrid

```
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');  

mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

  const message = `
    Name : ${body.name}\r\n
    Prenom : ${body.prenom}\r\n
    Adresse : ${body.adresse}\r\n
    Téléphone : ${body.telephone}\r\n
    email : ${body.email} \r\n
    Type de bien : ${body.message}\r\n
    Année de construction : ${body.annee}

  `;

 const data = {
    to: ?????? 
    from: 'souleymanportfolio@souleymanportfolio.com',
    subject: 'Nouveau Lead!',
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>')

  };



  mail.send(data);

  res.status(200).json({ status: 'Ok' });
```

Plz help, I am trying to put in const data = to the ${body.email}. To be simple, it's for sending e-mail while just typing in the front.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You can set the `to` property on the `data` object to `body.email` like so:

```js
 const data = {
    to: body.email,
    from: 'souleymanportfolio@souleymanportfolio.com',
    subject: 'Nouveau Lead!',
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>')
  };
```

Comment: Thank you I don't knowwhy it doesn't worked before. Kind of dumb :)

Comment: So, the code now works? If this answer did help, please mark it as correct so that others can see. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the help, and it's now an answer